# Is a snapshot of last login times a type of censored data?

Tags: censoring

I have a database of users with a field of the last time they logged in. Would this kind of data be considered "censored", and if so is there anything I can do with it beyond a histogram/density of how many people logged in within the last month, two months, etc? (To be clear: I only know the last time they logged in, so they could have logged in every day for years, up until a week ago, and all I know is they haven't logged in since last week.)

It feels to me that this is censored data, but in a reverse sort of way from the definitions I read online. But perhaps this is just left-censored data? Or is this some kind of logit problem?

For now, all I'm able to say is the percentage of users who have logged in during the last month, two months, etc, but I know people will want to hear more than that, and I also fear that it's easy to misinterpret what this data means. (It feels very particular, like explaining a confidence interval.) Ultimately, I may have to (manually) dump the data on a weekly basis to be able to take it any farther.

Any references appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to learn from your data?

Comment: @whuber: unfortunately, the answer is fairly broad: "how busy, how used, is this system?" Some people felt that the system was hardly used at all, but I've been able to show that 25% of possible users have logged in during the last 3 months, and 50% during the last 9 months, which gives a feeling that it's more than "hardly used at all". But that answer's not that satisfying, really, and I feel like it's easy to misinterpret what it means (e.g. "25% of users log in on a quarterly basis").